# FCM push with high priority to topic comes with delay

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I'm sending push messages to small group of devices (less than 5) subscribed to one topic with priority parameter set to **high**

> **High priority.** FCM attempts to deliver high priority messages
>   immediately, allowing the FCM service to wake a sleeping device when
>   possible and open a network connection to your app server. Apps with
>   instant messaging, chat, or voice call alerts, for example, generally
>   need to open a network connection and make sure FCM delivers the
>   message to the device without delay. Set high priority only if the
>   message is time-critical and requires the user's immediate
>   interaction, but beware that setting your messages to high priority
>   contributes more to battery drain compared with normal priority
>   messages.

But when I put device to IDLE state it comes with big delay. On Nougat 7.1 delay is more than 10 mins. This type of push requires delay less than 10 secs.

Setting `time_to_live` to 0 solves issues only on Marshmallow. Nougat still failing.

So, I see only 3 possible causes of issue

1. Messages sent to topic can't be high priority. But sending independent messages to each device will increase app-server load. I need to load fresh token from Firebase Database, so the result will be - 10 http requests for 5 users instead of 1.
2. App must be in whitelist. But according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#whitelisting-cases) it's not acceptable, if I'm using FCM. And I don't want it, because it will cause battery drain.
3. Bug? https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/100

If real cause is first, then why it isn't described in documentation?

Comment: Is your `delay_while_idle` set to `false`?

Comment: @AL `delay_while_idle` not set at all, default values is `false`. Also it will be deprecated tomorrow

Comment: Did you figure it out? Also is there a limit on high priority topic messages?

Comment: @Kushan I was tired of this and moved to OneSignal. It has device-to-device push, so I don't need server. Devices just getting all required push ids from Firebase DB and send push to them

Comment: @Dima Rostopira thanks man :)

Comment: Why isn't anyone answering? 1,404 people viewed this question. Nobody answered. Unbelievable.

Comment: @Pro because nobody knows, except people from Google, but looks like they don't care

Comment: @DimaRostopira Nobody gives a damn.

Comment: anyone with the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue solved by setting `time_to_live` to 0. According to docs, this set's priority to "now or never"

> Another advantage of specifying the lifespan of a message is that FCM
>   never throttles messages with a time_to_live (TTL) value of 0 seconds.
>   In other words, FCM guarantees best effort for messages that must be
>   delivered "now or never." Keep in mind that a time_to_live value of 0
>   means messages that can't be delivered immediately are discarded.
>   However, because such messages are never stored, this provides the
>   best latency for sending notification messages.

UPD: solved only for Marshmallow. On Nougat is still an issue.

UPD2: just don't use topics, they aren't intended for sending pushes without delay.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging):

> Topic messages are **optimized for throughput rather than latency**. For fast, secure delivery to single devices or small groups of devices, [target messages to registration tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices), not topics.